# Problem with running `git merge` on my new branch

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging, git-fetch

I have my work only on my master branch locally and remotely also I have an upstream from where I fetch updates and merge/push them to my master branch, the question is how should I properly execute git commands in order to:

1. create new branch "working"
2. Set remotes in that branch as remote master(same as now) and remote upstream
3. Fetch on that branch updates from upstream
4. And push them to my remote git repository but not on master but on my new branch -> I want to create branch also on my github.

I tried

```
-> git branch working
-> git checkout working (that's first step I hope)
```

I added remotes, so when I do -> git remote -v
I can see also my origin remote and my upstream remote

And now...

When I do

```
->git fetch upstream
->git merge -m "Merge upstream"
```

This is what I normally did when I wanted to update my repository
I get **fatal: No remote for the current branch.**
What Is the problem and how should I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

`git merge` takes a source revision as argument. Your command `git merge -m "Merge upstream"` misses it. so I would suggest appending a revision name like `upstream/master` like below:

```
git merge -m "Merge upstream" upstream/master
git push master HEAD:refs/heads/working # if the remote host is really "master" and branch is "working"
```